# I'm trying to print all columns in database to a horizontally table

Tags: php, html

I know I did something so stupid in my code but please help me . As you see I'm trying to print all the information in database horizontally and when I run this, it only grabs client and doesn't grab the other columns from database. I hope all the information I gave you is enough.

```
<table>
    <?php       $query = "SELECT * FROM 1d ORDER BY 'client' DESC";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="6" style="color:black;font-size:30;width: 5%;height:400px;background-color:white;"><p style="width:100px;white-space: nowrap;position: relative;right:50%;white-space: nowrap;    top: 57px;transform-origin: right;transform: rotate(-90deg);">1D : Preparation</p><br></th>
            <th style="width:200px;">Client</th>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
            <td ><?php echo $row['client']; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th >Produit</th>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
            <td ><?php echo $row['produit']; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th >Equipe</th>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
                <td ><?php echo $row['equipe']; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th >Date</th>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
                <td ><?php echo $row['pdate']; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th >Description de Probleme</th>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
                <td ><?php echo $row['descdpro']; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th >Pilote</th>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
                <td ><?php echo $row['pilote']; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should output a single row of column headers before the `<tbody>`. Then use ONE loop to output the rows with the all the `<td>` elements populated between a set of `<tr></tr>` tags inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_fetch_assoc iterate throug the `$result` variable one time. After the first cycle the others get false and you cannot see other elements than the first.

To avoid this you can populate an array with the results:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 1d ORDER BY 'client' DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $results = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $results[] = $row;
    }
?>
```

and change every cycle with this:

```
<?php foreach($results as $row){ ?>
     <td ><?php echo $row[ ... insert the key here ...]; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: We can do this using one loop only. Use the `while` loop for creating the table rows.

Comment: it worked for me just as I want it . thank you very much